# php load up a .php page and replace variable, and then store the output

Tags: php

I would like to load different .php page (the .php contain html and some php variable need to be replaced.

For example:

```
load.php
```

$output = '';

load the test.php and replace that $this->name with value.

store the html to $output

---

load the test1.php and replace that $this->name with value.

append to the previous $output variable

so at the end i would have a $output variable have all the updated html

Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

test.php
>

```
<html>
<?php echo $this->name; ?>
</html>
```

test1.php
>

```
<html>
<?php echo $this->address; ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely want to use output buffering with a require or include statement:

```
ob_start();

require('load.php');

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

`$output` should contain the contents of load.php with any variables processed.

To process multiple files (or anything else) just run it all between `ob_start()` and the last two lines, so you could grab two files like so:

```
ob_start();

require('test.php');
require('test1.php');

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```